# I get a classcast exception when I try to cast session.getAttribute?

Tags: java, jsp

i get a classcast exception when i try to cast session.getAttribute to a lessonselection bean, here is my work:

**bean class:**

```
public class LessonSelection implements Serializable{

private HashMap<String, Lesson> chosenLessons = new HashMap<String, Lesson>();
private int ownerID;
private DataSource ds = null;
private ResultSet rs = null;
private PreparedStatement st = null;
//private String LessonID;
//int counter for number of max lessons willl need to be 10.

public LessonSelection() {
}

public Set getItems() {
    return chosenLessons.entrySet();
}
```

**controller code:**

```
  if (action.equals("/lessonTimetable")) {
        if (request.getParameter("btnSelect") != null) {
            this.selectedLesson = session.getAttribute("lessons") == null ? new LessonSelection(getID) : (LessonSelection) session.getAttribute("lessons");
            lessons.ID = request.getParameter("lessonID");
            lessons.description = request.getParameter("lessonDescription");
            lessons.date = request.getParameter("lessonStartDate");
            lessons.startTime = request.getParameter("lessonStartTime");
            lessons.endTime = request.getParameter("lessonEndTime");
            lessons.level = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("lessonLevel"));
            System.out.println(lessons + "" + selectedLesson);
            this.selectedLesson.addLesson(lessons);
            session.setAttribute("lessons", this.selectedLesson.getItems());
            //check for duplicate lessons
            rd = this.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/LessonSelectionView.jspx");
```

**view:**

```
<c:forEach var="getAll" items="${lessons}">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <c:out value="${getAll.value.description}"/>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <c:out value="${getAll.value.date}"/>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <c:out value="${getAll.value.startTime}"/>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <c:out value="${getAll.value.endTime}"/>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <c:out value="${getAll.value.level}"/>
                        </td>
```

This exception only occurs when I try to add in the second lesson to the selected list, it will add the first but I'm having a problem in retrieving the previously created session.

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.HashMap$EntrySet cannot be cast to model.LessonSelection
```

, please could i have some help with this, it would be much appreciated

Comment: I feel there is a question coming, somewhere

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting just means that this line is wrong:

```
this.selectedLesson = session.getAttribute("lessons") == null ? new LessonSelection(getID) : (LessonSelection) session.getAttribute("lessons");
```

You are trying to cast `session.getAttribute("lessons")`, which is a `java.util.HashMap$EntrySet` into a `LessonSelection`. You just need to review this part of the code, i.e. what is actually the type of `session.getAttribute("lessons")` and why you are trying to cast it into the wrong type. You most probably need to change the type of some elements of your code.